# Where are plugins/tools installed from the Eclipse marketplace located on linux? (Mars)

Tags: linux, eclipse, filesystems, eclipse-mars, eclipse-marketplace

I installed Instasearch from the MarketPlace, and wanted to do some configuration on it. So I started looking for the installation directory but couldn't find it. I have searched all the eclipse and system directories and still no luck. So generally speaking, where do apps installed from the eclipse marketplace get installed on a linux system?

Answer (score 11):

Eclipse traditionally puts plugins in the Eclipse install location in a 'plugins' directory.

If that location is not writeable then a `.eclipse` directory in the user's home directory is used.

For newer Eclipse installs using the Oomph installer a `.p2` directory in the user's home directory is used.

Note: directories starting with `.` are usually hidden by Linux.